# How to add 5% buy and 5% sell fees to live-token?

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens

I want to add 5% Sell and 5% Buy Fees to a token contract on Remix[image]

The Token is already live, so i just want to update it from 0% to 5%.

But the numbers are all in uint256, what is the correct number for 5% in uint256 or where do i find a good converter for this?

Thanks very much!

Comment: It all depends on how the code interprets it. You need to have a look at how the fee is used when doing the math. You can share the code here so we can help.